# Theme styling for plugins

Tags: plugins, themes

I have a plugin that has it's own CSS for the content generated when you use the associated short codes. I am trying to create a theme to re-style the front end of my site but as this plugin has its own CSS how can i modify it from within my new theme?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? At least to me it's a bit hard to understand what your goal is and which problems you are facing.

Comment: CSS styles can be overwritten in various ways. Use the plugin's generated classes and style them in your theme with `!important`, but it's not a good practice in mass edit you know. Anyways, it's not a WordPress related question to me, it's rather a CSS related question only.

Comment: As you said its not good to overwrite massive amounts of styling so is it not possible just to change everything else on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Your two options are to [add your own stylesheet](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to redefine the plugin's styles, or remove the plugin's css file entirely by dequeueing the stylesheet (assuming the plugin has correctly added the stylesheet via the API)

```
function wpd_my_theme_css() {
    // dequeue plugin css with same handle it is enqueued with
    wp_dequeue_style( 'plugin_css_handle' );
}
// priority must by a higher number than the css is added on
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpd_my_theme_css', 9999 );
```

You'll have to look at the specific plugin's code for a definitive answer on what's possible here.